# Controller property is not updated

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to perform a simple login action in a `LoginController`, and trying to store the result in a `loggedIn` property of the controller. In `tryLogin()` of the controller,when I make ajax call and set the property of the controller using `App.LoginController.loggedIn=true` that is not reflected in the controller.

please check this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ixupad/264/)

I am suspecting something wrong with the my understanding of the scoping, but not able to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `loggedIn` property on the controller instance, not the controller class definition.  Which means you need to use `self.set('loggedIn', true)` instead of `App.LoginController.loggedIn = true`.

Another thing to remember, always use `object.set('prop', 'val')` instead of `object.prop = 'val'`

Here's the [updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ixupad/267)

Comment: Thanks,but In global level, how would I get the instance of the LoginController ,am I supposed to use the instance globally?

Comment: No, controllers are not supposed to be accessed from the global level.  From the route, use `this.controllerFor('login')`, from the controller use the `needs` dependency: http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/